# Don't immediately stop child Akka actors when parent actor stopped

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have an actor `p: ParentActor` which I want to do some cleanup jobs when it is stopped by making use of the `postStop` method. One of the jobs involves sending a message to a child actor `c: ChildActor`. After that, `c` and then `p` should be stopped. However, once `context.stop(p)` has been called `c` seems to be immediately stopped and is unable to receive messages.

Below is an example of what I'd like to do:

```
class ParentActor extends Actor {
  ...
  override def postStop {
    logger.info("Shutdown message received. Sending message to child...")
    val future = c ? "doThing"
    logger.info("Waiting for child to complete task...")
    Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
    context.stop(c)
    logger.info("Child stopped. Stopping self. Bye!")
    context.stop(self)
  }
}
```

Results in error message:

```
[ERROR] [SetSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://SetSystem/user/ParentActor] Recipient[Actor[akka://SetSystem/user/ParentActor/ChildActor#70868360]] had already been terminated. Sender[Actor[akka://SetSystem/user/ParentActor#662624985]] sent the message of type "java.lang.String".
```

An alternative would be to send `p` a message saying to shutdown, and have the above actions take place as a result of that, but using the built in stopping functionality seems better.

PS. This is a new application so design alternatives are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an actor `A` is stopped, its children are indeed stopped before `A`'s `postStop` hook is called. The sequence of events when an actor is stopped is as follows (from the official [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/actors.html#stopping-actors)):

> Termination of an actor proceeds in two steps: first the actor suspends its mailbox processing and sends a stop command to all its children, then it keeps processing the internal termination notifications from its children until the last one is gone, finally terminating itself (invoking `postStop`, dumping mailbox, publishing `Terminated` on the DeathWatch, telling its supervisor).

Overriding the parent's `postStop` won't help you because your desired shutdown procedure includes sending a message to a child and waiting for a reply. When the parent is terminated, the child is stopped before the parent's `postStop` is run.

As you mentioned, sending a specific message to the `ParentActor` to initiate the shutdown is another approach. Something like the following would work:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

class ParentActor extends Actor {
  ...
  def receive = {
    case Shutdown =>
      (c ? DoYourThing).mapTo[ThingIsDone].pipeTo(self)
    case ThingIsDone =>
      logger.info("Child has finished its task.")
      context.stop(self)
    case ...
  }
}
```

Note that one should avoid using `Await` in an actor. Instead, [pipe](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/futures.html#use-with-actors) the result of a `Future` to an actor.